# Negative scores with cts:reverse-query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

While using `search:resolve()` function with a `serialized cts:reverse-query()`, I observed that every `search:result` element has value '-256' for its score attribute.

```
i.e. <search:result index="12" uri="<some-uri>" path="fn:doc("<some-uri>")" score="-256" confidence="-0" fitness="-0">
```

Can someone please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Can you share the reverse query you are using? Have you set the quality of any of your documents to be less than 0?

Comment: I have not set quality for documents. Everything is set to default.

**Query** :    `search:resolve(document{cts:reverse-query($text)}/*)`
where $text is text paragraph.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete test case to make it easier to test on our side? I see no immediate explanation..